# Is this 'providing' a conjunction or an adjective verb?

Tags: interpretation

I wonder it's clear to natives whether **providing** is a conjunction or a adjective verb. How about this one?

> The Giants aren't the first sports team to dabble in **providing** fans with wireless Internet service or Web access at their seats. (San Francisco Chronicle, 2004)

Comment: Yes, it would be quite clear to native speakers what "part of speech" ***providing*** is here. Even if they don't know the terminology (it's actually a [*gerund*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gerund) here), they know that people (and sports teams) *dabble in **activities***, which are ***nouns***. And here, the gerund is the noun. Is there an actual question?

Comment: I think you don't know that this place is for English "learners".

Comment: You asked whether it's ***clear to natives*** what terminology applies here. I simply pointed out that even though most native speakers wouldn't know the specific ***term*** "gerund" (or "noun", in some cases), they'd recognise that the same basic *concept / lexical class* applies to both ***I like fish*** (a *thing/substance* you can eat) and ***I like fishing*** (a *thing / activity* you can carry out). And it should be fairly obvious to anyone, learner or not, that ***I like providing answers to ELL questions*** is the same basic construction as the latter.

Comment: You said "Is there an actual question? " and I replied to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is neither. What it **is** depends on what grammatical sect you follow.

Note that *providing* follows *in*. The object of a preposition must be an NP, an nominal entity.

Consequently, traditional grammar takes *providing* to be the object of *in* and calls it a *gerund*, an *-ing* form acting as a noun.

Contemporary phrase-structure grammars take the entire non-finite clause which *providing* heads to be the object of *in* and call the word itself the *predicator*, a very highfalutin way of naming the function enacted by a verb.

Answer (score 0):

It's neither; it's a [gerund](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund) (colloquially, an "-ing word"), a form of a verb (in this case "provide") used as a noun. Here it's part of the noun phrase "providing fans with wireless Internet service or Web access at their seats," the activity in which the Giants are dabbling.

Verbs conjugated with "-ing" *can* also be used as adjectives (they're called "gerundives" when used like this), as in "caring parents" or "loving wife", but using "providing" in this way doesn't sound right to my ear, and it's definitely not what's happening in the example you gave.

---

As a side note, "**provided**" can be used as a conjunction; it's a synonym for "if":

> You can go to the party, provided you're home by 12.

Comment: +1 But an *-ing* form deployed as an adjective is usually called a *present participle*. *Gerundive* is deprecated these days, since it denotes a Latin future passive participle which has very little in common with English present participles.